# Which key Harmonica to use in conjunction with Distorted Electric Guitar in C#/D half step down

Tags: guitar, theory, electric-guitar, blues, harmonica

I'm in a melodic metalcore band, and we're looking to include some harmonica riffs/solos in some songs. We're currently writing in C# or D half step down and would like some help in this subject. We're thinking C# or G#, would either of these work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a song in C#, the more melodic parts need a C# harp. To get a bluesy sound/feel, you'll need an F# harp, which will give a blues sound when sucked, or drawn, producing C#7 and C#9.

Comment: Okay, I was a little hesitant to try an F# because I thought it was uncomfortably high. Thoughts? Also, I may go with C#, but does that rule out any other lower harps, like G#?

Comment: How do you mean - uncomfortably high? The more important factor is will it play the right notes.

Comment: Oh, I just feel that it's very high pitched, I'm not sure what it'll sound like with C# distorted guitar. I see what you're saying though. I think I'll get a cheapo F# if I can find one and test the waters. Thanks you for your expertise!